# Google is sending people to Stack Overflow with a blunt instrument

Tags: discussion

This is sending everyone with a question, or gripe, or opinion, about [BigQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigQuery) to Stack Overflow:

```
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/bigquery-discuss/z5Z-aRS9z8I
```

That resulted, so far, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553544/why-does-google-bigquery-not-support-protcol-buffers). Perhaps someone from the team should add a message to their forum, or contact them, and explain the rules?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

<s>One ranty non-question in almost 7 months? It doesn't seem too bad.</s> <sup>(see below)</sup>

I don't know for certain, but I'm pretty sure Google as a company understands what Stack Overflow is about. Several teams there have been using SO to provide developer support and it's been working pretty well far as I know.

To me their post reads like they're sending their *technical* support to us. If one person (or even a few people) misunderstand what that means... we have the tools to easily handle it. If it becomes a more widespread issue, though, I agree - it'd be worth tracking someone down to make clarifications.

---

At this time, there are 8 closed questions in [google-bigquery](/questions/tagged/google-bigquery), of which 7 were posted after May 1 (the date on the Google Groups post linked in the question):

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261674/unable-to-upload-csv-file-from-local-in-bigquery-table - not enough information to answer
- [How does BigQuery query / analysis pricing work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282798/can-someone-explain-how-bigquery-query-analysis-pricing-works) - not programming related
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341717/how-do-i-append-a-csv-file-from-local-to-a-bigquery-table-that-already-have-some - duplicate
- [BigQuery, SLAs and support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041372/bigquery-slas-and-support) - not programming related
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044521/who-is-using-bigquery - not programming related
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166282/response-too-large-error-on-composite-query-but-each-individual-query-runs-fine - not enough information to answer
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392277/bigquery-queries-are-failing-with-unexpected-please-try-again - not enough information to answer

There are also 14 deleted questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954805/what-is-the-connection-limit-on-bigquery - Programming-related, deleted by the asker.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396342/how-can-i-use-google-bigquery-with-c-net - programming-related, though a poor fit for SO. Closed by community and deleted by moderator.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048442/implementation-of-mpu-6050-low-power-pedometer - I don't even know what this is about. Deleted automatically for being too old and downvoted.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353519/how-to-access-google-bigquery-api-using-c - same as the C# question above, but deleted automatically this time.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470434/bigquery-api-accessing-from-more-than-one-developers - programming-related (I think), deleted by the asker.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526252/r-client-for-bigquery - bad fit for SO, closed and deleted by the community.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770156/query-about-the-service-or-technology-behind-gmail-service - a general "how things work" question, likely mistagged. Closed by community + moderator, deleted automatically.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774177/expression-returning-infinity - programming-related, self-answered, and ultimately deleted by the asker.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131554/files-being-deleted-from-cloud-storage-during-bq-load - looks programming-related, deleted by the asker.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13312463/how-do-i-insert-a-timestamp-into-bigquery - programming-related, deleted by the asker.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13440881/get-data-from-bigquery-based-on-a-query-from-app-engine-service-account - programming-related, deleted by the asker.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13481501/join-a-table-on-fields-whose-names-include-dots - programming-related, deleted by the asker.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532218/in-bigquery-able-to-retrieve-data-through-limit-but-not-where - programming-related, deleted by the asker.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553544/why-does-google-bigquery-not-support-protcol-buffers - the rant that brought us here to meta.

There are currently 250 open questions remaining in [google-bigquery](/questions/tagged/google-bigquery). As you can see, it's a low-volume tag with fairly few misses in terms of the question content. While it's not "one post in seven months" that I originally referred to, it's still not a widespread problem and I think the system's working as intended.

Comment: Just like Facebook. Am I right?

Comment: @casperOne Sort of, yeah, though on a different scale and with a different demographic.

Comment: How do we know that was "One ranty non-question in almost 7 months"?  That question was closed and **deleted within an hour.**  How many others disappeared like that?  We can't even use SEDE to see if it's a real problem.

Comment: @AwesomePoodles See my edit for a more specific analysis.

Comment: Thanks for the hard data, Anna.   So, yes, that tag doesn't look like it's attracting more bad questions than usual.